# Derivation of exponential (in a general algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, simplex

There is a curious formula relating the derivation of an exponential in some, possibly noncommutative (associative) algebra, namely
$$
D(e^K) = \int_0^1 e^{(1-s)K}D(K)e^{sK} ds
$$
where $D$ is a derivation (it verifies the usual Leibniz rule) and $K$ is a nilpotent element (there exists some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K^n = 0$).

The first idea would be to write
$$
D(e^K) = D\left( \displaystyle\sum_{l\geq 0} \frac{K^l}{l!} \right)
=
 \displaystyle\sum_{l\geq0} \frac{1}{l!} D(K^l)
$$
Now we apply the Leibniz rule:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
D(K^l) &=& D(K)K^{l-1} + K D(K^{l-1}) 
\\
&=& D(K)K^{l-1} + K D(K) K^{l-2} + K^2D(K^{l-2})
\\
&=& \dots
\\
&=& \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^l K^{j-1} D(K) K^{l-j}
\end{array}
$$
Then we arrived to
$$
D(e^K) = \sum_{l\geq 0} \sum_{j=0}^l \dfrac{1}{l!} K^{j-1} D(K)K^{l-j}
$$
The latter sum is over all integer points inside, say, the first octant of the plane. The horizontal direction being the $l$-direction and the vertical one is the $j$-direction.
Using Fubini's theorem, we transform the sum of the vertical slices of the first octant into the sum of its horizontal slices:
$$
\sum_{l\geq 0} \sum_{j=0}^l \dfrac{1}{l!} K^{j-1} D(K)K^{l-j} = \sum_{j \geq 0} \sum_{l \geq j} \dfrac{1}{l!} K^{j-1} D(K)K^{l-j}
$$
Then set $m= l-j$ to get
$$
 \sum_{j \geq 0} \sum_{m \geq 0} \dfrac{1}{(m+j)!} K^{j-1} D(K)K^{m}
$$
I guess the coefficient $(m+j)!$ should be related with some integration over the $1$-simplex $\{(1-s,s): s\in [0,1]\}$ but I couldn't find yet.

Any hint to finish the proof of the formula? Or maybe a clever approach ?

Comment: ps: the algebra is over a field of characteristic zero.

Comment: Wait, what is this integral supposed to mean in a field of characteristic $0$? Like, what is the measure on $[0;1]$, and actually what is $[0;1]$ in the first place? You're sure you don't just want to field to be $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I guess $[0,1]$ stands for the 1-simplex. If the field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ it is ok for me. Maybe you can see this integral as a "sum" of element in $A[t]$ where $A$ is the algebra where $K$ belongs.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is usually called Duhamel's formula in the math literature and it is also valid for general $K$ (without the requirement of being nilpotent). Here is an elementary derivation.

Consider

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}e^{(A+B)t}e^{-At} &=e^{(A+B)t}(A+B)e^{-At}-e^{(A+B)t}Ae^{-At} \\
 &=e^{(A+B)t}Be^{-At},
\end{align}

now integrate both sides from zero to one:

$$
e^{A+B}e^{-A}- 1 =\int_{0}^{1}dt \, e^{(A+B)t}Be^{-At}
$$
from which we obtain

$$
e^{A+B}-e^{A}=\int_{0}^{1}dt \, e^{(A+B)t}Be^{(1-t)A}.
$$

Now set $B=\epsilon D(A)$ and, assuming that $A$ is differentiable,  we obtain

\begin{align}
De^{A} & =\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{e^{(A+\epsilon DA)}-e^{A }}{\epsilon} \\
 &=\int_{0}^{1}dt\, e^{At}D(A)e^{(1-t)A} . 
\end{align}

Comment: @peterag Yes absolutely. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first part is nice! Nevertheless in the second part I just want $D$ to be a general derivation (not necessarily the usual differential). To situate the context you can have a look at the article of D. Quillen: Algebra cochains and cyclic cohomology (equation (7.2) p.168).

Comment: You're welcome. I think I can give a more algebraic derivation (tomorrow).

Comment: Maybe the proof given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403389/duhamels-formula) would work. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes exactly. This is what I had in mind. Use the product formula for the exponential.

Comment: But if we do like that, the derivation must be assumed to be continuous... am I wrong ? (the first identity they invert $D$ and $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134392/discussion-between-lcv-and-quentin).